# How to store complicated object (with knockout observables) locally?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a very simple chat protocol that is integrated with sending site-related data between clients:

```
var ThreadList = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.threads = ko.observableArray(); //Thread[]
    //more members
}

var Thread = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.messages = ko.observableArray(); //Message[]
    //more members
}

var Message = function(source){
    var self = this;

    self.header = ko.computed(function(){
        //logic
    }, self);

    self.body = ko.observable();
    //more members
}
```

A thread is a simple discussion thread between two members, and every thread contains several messages between these members.  Multiple threads are contained with the ThreadList object.

How can I go about storing this information locally?  Using `localStorage` would require a large amount of extra code to serialize every single member and their values.

Comment: The question does not make sense to me. A messaging application will use either a server or a p2p connection. Storing a conversation locally is just a detail once you've managed to make two computers actually exchange data.

Comment: The clients are talking to each other just fine, I just don't want to have to pull every conversation from the server every time the clients renavigate pages, it's a noticeable performance hit for the client and it's not the most scale-able solution to have them pull from the server every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about the code for serializing the data, knockoutJS has a function ko.toJS(object). This would return the serialized data.

```
var serializedData = ko.toJS(ThreadList);
```

That would return the serialized data.

Comment: Thanks, i'll get around to testing this out!

Comment: It did work, so at least serialization won't be hard.  Making another constructor though to repopulate it is just cost of development i guess ha.

Comment: @jokulmorder You'd probably want to use the [`knockout mapping` plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to deserialize.